# Induction heating directly from AC wall power

Tags: heat, induction, circuits

I am working on a project converting a 220 volt resistance heating kiln into an induction heating crucible furnace for melting black sand concentrates from a precious metals mine, which are comprised mostly of iron sand.

My question is, where the resistance kiln already steps the amperage up and the voltage down from 220 volts, can I simply connect the induction coil to the power feed to the kilns resistance heating elements?

I want to disconnect the resistance heating elements from the kiln and connect my induction coil to the power source.

My induction coil is a 1-in copper tube with water pumped through it to keep it cool.

I already know that designing an induction heating circuit specifically for the application would be most efficient, but, for now, I just need an induction crucible furnace to do several batches.

I already know that the 60 HZ of the kiln circuit is appropriate for heating iron.

The kiln circuit appears to maintain alternating current from the wall to the elements.

The kiln appears to control the amount of heating in the elements by switching three layers of windings on the transformer on and off.

I just need to know if I'm going to damage anything by hooking up to the induction coil.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Welcome. It is most doubtful that your resistance kiln does any voltage stepdown as you say. Usually the heating elements operate directly at line voltage. Also, 60 Hz is not a reasonable frequency for an induction heater for iron or any other metal. It might be good to post a picture of what you already have to see if any of this can be cleared up.

Comment: If you connect an air core induction coil directly to line voltage you will trip a circuit breaker or blow a fuse very quickly. The induction coil is basically a short circuit.

Comment: If your "resistance kiln already steps the amperage up and the voltage down from 220 volts" then it must be using a transformer but it seems irrelevant to the question. Induction heaters usually operate in the hundreds of kilohertz range,  not 60 Hz.

Comment: I think an induction coil for iron/steel could operate down as low as 10 or 20 kHz. But I don't work in that industry. I just remember that number from a few years ago when I took an interest in the topic and did some research.

Comment: You will encounter difficulty implementing induction heating at a low frequency like 60Hz unless you use a large number of turns in your coil, rather than a large coil carrying a lot of current. As others have said, a copper pipe, even if twisted into a coil, is going to be a virtual short. Some back of the envelope calculations suggest that a 220V induction heating coil 10cm in diameter with 1000 turns would draw about 1kW of reactive power. 1000 turns of wire that can carry a minimum of 5A is a lot of copper, and you will have difficulty getting by with less. You probably need >> twice that.